# Ruby - Matching all patterns in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Need help with matching all patterns in a string.

```
s1 = " countries like US, Japan, Korea, Vietnam, Germany"
s2 = " countries like Holland, China, Korea, Thailand, UK"
```

From the above string need to match specific Asian countries

```
regex = /(Japan)|(Korea)|(Vietnam)|(Cambodia)|(China)|(Thailand)/


irb(main):157:0> s1.match(regex)
=> #<MatchData "Japan" 1:"Japan" 2:nil 3:nil 4:nil>
```

Is there a way to get the following output?

```
s1.some_regex_operation # => Japan, Korea, Vietnam
s2.some_regex_operation # => China, Korea, Thailand
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to match consecutive occurrences of such countries as a single string, or do you want to match any instance of such country throughout the string?

Comment: Wanted to match as per the example string output mentioned above. That is all occurrences in a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
s1 = " countries like US, Japan, Korea, Vietnam, Germany"
s2 = " countries like Holland, China, Korea, Thailand, UK"
s1.scan(/Japan|Korea|Vietnam|Cambodia|China|Thailand/)
# => ["Japan", "Korea", "Vietnam"]
s2.scan(/Japan|Korea|Vietnam|Cambodia|China|Thailand/)
# => ["China", "Korea", "Thailand"]
```

Comment: This may or may not be the correct answer. The OP is not clear on this. It is the OP's fault.

Comment: @sawa The checkmark does seem to clear up the ambiguity, though.